# getting an endless loop - react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to set this code to inc. the count..

```
class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
  };

  add() {
    this.setState((state) => {
      return { count: 5 };
    });
  }

  render() {
    let classes = this.getBadgeClasses();
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCounter()}</span>
        <button onClick={this.add()} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
          Increment
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

whats wrong ??

Comment: note: count :5 is just for stopping the loop...

Comment: `<button onClick={this.add} className='btn btn-secondary btn-sm'>Increment</button>`
Don't call the function while setting the onClick handler

Comment: didnt work. thanks :)

Comment: Since you are using class based components, you may need `.bind()` too. Please go through the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<button onClick={this.add()}>Increment</button>
```

with

```
<button onClick={() => this.add()}>Increment</button>
```